# Return only repeated strings (not same order, same letters)

Tags: java

I have a list of strings:
[‘papi’, ‘polo’, ‘lopo’, ‘appi, ‘abba’, ‘polo’, ‘mama’]

How can I return only:

[‘papi’, ‘polo’, ‘lopo’, ‘appi’, ‘polo’]

Meaning the only strings that doesn’t repeat themself in the same letters/numbers of letters.
Need an answer in java.
Also it needs to be efficient.
Thanks.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean need an answer, first try by yourself

Comment: What's your attempt to solve this? Show us what you've done code wise and we'll point out what's going wrong if it doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: It sounds like you mean strings that **do** repeat themselves. LIke `lopo` and `polo` contain the same letters and are the same length so return them in the list.

Comment: What is the rule? Can you explain it. Why do polo and loo pass while mama doesnt?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a map `Map<String,List<String>>`
2. For each entry in the source list, create the key for that map by ordering the letters in the string alphabetically ("papi" and "appi" both will get "aipp" then)
3. Lookup the map for that key; if it exists, append the source String to the list. If not, create an new entry with the source String as the only entry of the new list
4. After you processed the source list, iterate over the map's values and print the contents of all lists with more than one single entry

Based on this it should be easy to write the corresponding Java code yourself …

EDIT ------8<-----

… but because today is a bit boring, here my solution for this question:

```
import static java.lang.System.err;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import static java.util.Arrays.sort;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 *  Finds those words in the give list that uses the same character set as at
 *  least one other word on the list.
 */
public class FindSameWordsUsingTheSameSetOfCharacters
{
        /*-----------*\
    ====** Constants **========================================================
        \*-----------*/
    /**
     *  The input list.
     */
    public static final String [] INPUT = { "papi", "polo", "lopo", "appi", "abba", "polo", "mama" };

        /*---------*\
    ====** Methods **==========================================================
        \*---------*/
    /**
     *  The program entry point.
     *
     *  @param  args    The command line arguments.
     */
    public static void main( final String... args )
    {
        try
        {
            final Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
            for( final var string : INPUT )
            {
                final var chars = string.toCharArray();
                sort( chars );
                final var key = new String( chars );
                map.computeIfAbsent( key, $ -> new ArrayList<>() ).add( string );
            }

            final var result = map.values()
                .stream()
                .filter( list -> list.size() > 1 )
                .flatMap( list -> list.stream() )
                .collect( joining( ", ", "[", "]" ) );
            out.printf( "Result: %s", result );
        }
        catch( final Throwable t )
        {
            //---* Handle any previously unhandled exceptions *----------------
            t.printStackTrace( err );
        }
    }   //  main()
}
//  class FindSameWordsUsingTheSameSetOfCharacters
```

I think with a bit more mapping magic this can be solved even without the `Map<> map`, and perhaps that version would return exact the output provided in the question.

This version delivers

```
Result: [papi, appi, polo, lopo, polo]
```

instead of the required

```
[‘papi’, ‘polo’, ‘lopo’, ‘appi’, ‘polo’]
```

(The sequence is different …).

Answer (score 0):

- Create a `HashMap<String, Integer>`
- Loop over the input and increment count for corresponding string in the HashMap
- Create an empty list of string (lets call it result)
- Loop over [`HashMap#keySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet()) and check if `count > 1`. If it is, add it to the result list.

Comment: How can I know which strings are corresponding? One string is pool and other is poop etc. how should you do it?

Comment: @Ofer `HashMap<String, Integer>` uses strings as key. If a string already exists, you know you need to increase the count.

Answer (score -1):

> doesn’t repeat themself in the same letters/numbers of letters

Since all your inputs are 4 letters, you're basically saying that the first 2 letters cannot be the same as the last 2 letters.

But let's assume strings can be any number of letters, which means we need to check any substring length that is divisible into the full string length, e.g. if string is 6 letters when substrings with length 2 and 3 needs to be checked, and if string is 7 letters we don't need to check anything.

To check if 2 substrings have the same set of letters, but in a potentially different order, normalize the substrings by sorting the letters, e.g. `pam` -> `amp`. The use a `Set` to check if you've already seen that normalized substring.

```
public static boolean isRepeating(String input) {
    int maxlen = input.length() / 2;
    for (int len = 2; len <= maxlen; len++)
        if (input.length() % len == 0 && isRepeating(input, len))
            return true;
    return false;
}

private static boolean isRepeating(String input, int len) {
    Set<String> substrings = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i += len) {
        char[] chars = input.substring(i, i + len).toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(chars);
        String normalizedSubstring = new String(chars);
        if (! substrings.add(normalizedSubstring))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

*Test*

```
List<String> input = Arrays.asList("papi", "polo", "lopo", "appi", "abba", "polo", "mama");
for (String str : input)
    System.out.printf("%-5s  %s%n", isRepeating(str), str);
```

*Output*

```
false  papi
false  polo
false  lopo
false  appi
true   abba
false  polo
true   mama
```

*Build New List*

```
List<String> input = Arrays.asList("papi", "polo", "lopo", "appi", "abba", "polo", "mama");
List<String> output = input.stream()
        .filter(s -> ! isRepeating(s))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(output); // prints: [papi, polo, lopo, appi, polo]
```

Comment: 1) What is this checking? 
            if (! substrings.add(normalizedSubstring))
2) Why don't we need to check a string that doesn't divide by 2?

Comment: 1) [`add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-) return false if the value is already in the set, i.e. if the value is a duplicate. --- 2) That was my interpretation of your *"doesn’t repeat themself in the same letters/numbers of letters"* when applied to inputs of more than 4 characters, i.e. to check if the content is a repeating pattern. E.g. `abab` is `ab` repeated twice, `ababab` is `ab` repeated twice, `abcabc` is `abc` repeated 3 times, but `ababa` and `xabab` are not equal to *full* repetitions of any substring.

Comment: OK , sorry so maybe my question needs to sharpen.
for example, we can have :

I have a list of strings: [‘papi’, ‘polo’, ‘lopo’, ‘appi, ‘abba’, ‘polo’, ‘mami’]

How can I return only:

[‘papi’, ‘polo’, ‘lopo’, ‘appi’, ‘polo’]

(it doesn't concern to repeated letters, for example mami and papa words are not written in other form. mami is not repeated as maim, and papa is not repteaed as apap

Comment: But if we have "mami" and also "maim" in the list then we will return both in the new 'output' list.
Same with "papa", if we had "papa" and also "apap" then both would have been inserted to the new list.

Comment: @Ofer Then I totally misunderstood the question. Yes, you should **edit** and clarify the question, explaining like you just did in the comment. [Answer by tquadrat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60553292/5221149) is what you're looking for, where step 2 involves normalizing the string similar to how I normalized substrings.